# DRF testing Model Serializer - Django Restframework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am testing my Serializer model in django restframework with `APITestCase`.
this is my structure :

```
class Usertest(APITestCase):
    def test_userprofile_create(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username='asghar', 
                                   password='4411652A', 
                                   email='ww@gmail.com',)
        profile = UserProfile.objects.create(fullname='asghariiiiii', 
                                             phonenumber='9121345432',
                                             address='bella', 
                                             user=user)
        user.user_profile = profile
        client = APIClient()
        request = client.get('/user/create/')
        data = UserCreateSerializer(user, 
                                    context={'request': request}).data

        url = reverse('user-create')
        response_create =client.post(url, data)
```

in my view permissions set to `AllowAny`.
no need for login or force_authenticate.

> data = UserCreateSerializer(user, context={'request': request}).data AttributeError: 'HttpResponseNotFound' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'

as you can see error comes from creating `data` .first i tried to remove `context` but error comes with this title :

> AssertionError: `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> request = client.get('/user/create/')

This returns a response, not a request. You should be able to work this around by using [`APIRequestFactory`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apirequestfactory):

```
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory

# Using the standard RequestFactory API to create a form POST request
factory = APIRequestFactory()
request = factory.post('/user/create/', {})
data = UserCreateSerializer(user, 
                                context={'request': request}).data
```

Answer (score 0):

REST_FRAMEWORK Request  doesn't have method build_absolute_uri

```
return request.build_absolute_uri(url)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'
```

DRF Request and Django HTTP Request isnt the same.